# Trying to run my ios app on ipad without membership (jailbroken 5.1.1)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, cydia

I'm trying to test my app on a jailbroken phone and followed the following link.

http://mhassan.me/2013/02/15/using-xcode-without-provisioning-profile/

I'm having issue when I'm trying to run it, It would throw in this error:

Could not launch “Tournament Admin”

No such file or directory (/Users/malupetako/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Tournament_Admin-fxtqgpqcnolfqvgaeikbuxwzdbcv/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Tournament Admin.app/Tournament Admin)

Not really sure what I missed there since I followed the steps to the T. And the link didn't really show that problem.

Thoughts?

Comment: Try [this tutorial at sysrage.net instead](http://www.sysrage.net/guides/ios-programming/building-and-running-ios-applications-without-a-paid-developer-license) - I've seen some people report better success with it.

Comment: Just saw this comment, sorry I didn't get to reply. I'll try it out. Thanks!